# Connection timed out. org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException when launching play 2.2.1

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework-2.0, java-7, timeoutexception

I run the play 2.2.1 (JVM 1.7) in the console. When I try to connect with my (eclipse) IDE i get the following error after it got stucked on 92% of the connection process..

Connection timed out.
org.eclipse.jdi.TimeoutException

I didnt find any helpful things on google.

I set up play on port 9000 and debug configuration in eclipse is the same.

Is there someone able to help me with this?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You started play with 'play debug' so that it listens for debug connections? Also, the default port play opens for debugging is 9999, 9000 is the http port for browsing.